# PATH-variable gets always reset. How to fix that?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

A little time ago, I found out, that I can create custom commandterminals with expanding the PATH-variable. Unfortunately, it gets always resettet, when I close the terminal and opens it again.

**Do you know how to fix this problem?**

Because when I want to start a few scripts with terminalcommands, I don't want to expand the PATH-variable everytime before ...

Comment: Put it in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: How to do that? I'm new on Linux ;)

Comment: open your `.bashrc` file like so: `gedit ~/.bashrc` and put whatever you want in there (at the bottom of the file is better), e.g., `PATH="~/my/cool/path/:$PATH"` and export this variable: after the line you just entered, put `export PATH` then save the file, then close your terminal and reopen it and now your executables in `~/my/cool/path` will be found.

Comment: I wrote it up as a full answer for you... `:)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a directory to the PATH?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I understand you have some executables in one of your home folders, e.g., in `~/bin` and you want to be able to execute them without always typing the full path `~/bin/my_cool_executable`.

You already observed that entering `PATH=~/bin:$PATH` in your terminal made things work... but only until you close the terminal. When you open a new one, your former `PATH` variable gets reset to its original value. By the way, I guess you know how to, at any time, check the value of the `PATH` variable: like so:

```
echo "$PATH"
```

How to make your change permanent so that your `PATH` will still be the same when you reopen a new terminal? It's very easy, you just need to edit your `.bashrc` file. Let's use the `gedit` editor: In a terminal, type this:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

This opens up the `gedit` editor. Scroll to the end of the file and add this:

```
# Added by me on 2013/06/24
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

and save the file and quit `gedit`. Then close your terminal and open a new one. Now your `PATH` variable should have `~/bin` in front of it so that your commands in `~/bin` will be accessible without typing their full path. And you know how to check that: `echo "$PATH"`.

Enjoy!

*Warning*. It is considered bad practice and a security vulnerability to put `.` in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: So, that was really nice, but now I can't start the programs, when I am root. Do you know why and how to fix that? :)

Comment: In this case, one option is to put your programs in `/usr/local/bin` instead of fiddling with the `PATH` variable... or in `/usr/local/sbin` if they must only be accessed by root.

Comment: Some have to be ran as root and some not. So it would be nice, if it wouldn't matter and they could be in a custom directory. So ist it able to do that? :)

Comment: somehow it won't work for a full path. PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin:$PATH